# Why cant i log in with phpseclib in mvc?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

i was testing my code only in my controler and it worked, when i went to put all in the model and call the functions in the controller it wont connect to the sftp server.

```
    require "vendor/autoload.php";
    use phpseclib\Net\SFTP;

class sftpInno extends SFTP{

        private $Host;
        private $Port;
        private $Username;
        private $Password;


    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->Host = '192.168.61.192';
        $this->Port = '99';
        $this->Username = 'tester';
        $this->Password = 'password';

    }

    public function SFTPLogin()
    {
        $return = true;

        if (!$this->login($this->Username, $this->Password)) {
            $return = false;
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

Controller

```
    $InnoSFT = new sftpInno();

$return = $InnoSFT->SFTPLogin();
```

Any toughts? Thanks

Comment: can we see the `SFTP` class please?

Comment: **..and any errors**, my guess the controller is in a namespace and the file is not found.

Comment: SFTP is phpseclib\Net\SFTP, not mine. I have no errors, when i debug and pause, it just wont put out any errors.

Comment: The controller and the module comunicate all other functions they work besides those who need the login into the sftp server.

Answer (score 2):

You should do `parent::__construct($this->Host, $this->Port)` in your constructor. The constructor for phpsecib's SFTP class (and SSH2 class) *do* do stuff after all:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.21/phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php#L273
https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/2.0.21/phpseclib/Net/SSH2.php#L953

If you have further issues then update your post to include the SSH logs. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', 2);` at the top and then `echo $this->getLog();` after the login attempt.

Comment: thanks dude, i was missing those in the construct. Thanks alot! cheers